# Unable to launch Gnome System Log Viewer after setting filters

Tags: logs, gnome3, filter, glib

I am unable to launch Gnome System Log Viewer after setting some filters. This is so, even after rebooting and reinstalling this GUI program. I found the following relevant line in /var/log/messages:

> kernel - [ 2345.123456] traps: logview[1234] trap int3 ip:32682504e9
>   sp:7fff9123c150 error:0

It seems to be some exception error with the kernel. How to deal with it and get the viewer to launch again?

**UPDATE:**

I tried launching it manually with the following command: `gnome-system-log` and it gives me a more verbose error:

> GLib-GIO-ERROR **: g_menu_item_set_detailed_action: Detailed action
>   name 'win.filter_hide info' has invalid format Trace/breakpoint trap

It appears that the regex I wrote for `win.filter_hide` has some invalid format. How can I access this and change it manually without the GUI?

**UPDATE2:**

I tried:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-system-log filters
@as []
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.gnome-system-log filters
```

It doesn't work. I think I am somewhere close, but not sure how to access `win.filter_hide` from here. From this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S01q4.png), I don't see how installing `dconf-editor` would help me access that filter.

**UPDATE3:**

I finally manage to take a peep at the values by logging in as root:

```
# gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-system-log filters
['hide info:1:::\\tinfo', 'error:0:#efef29292929::\\terr', 'show all:0:#000000000000::\\d']
# gsettings reset org.gnome.gnome-system-log filters
(process:3453): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
```

Not sure where is the problem. But as can be seen, I can't even do a reset when logged on as root. And I can't access those values when logged on as normal user.

**UPDATE4:**

Finally it is solved. The reason why connection is closed is because the root is logged in the user environment. This should work:

```
$ su -c "gsettings reset org.gnome.gnome-system-log filters" -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter settings are saved as a gsettings scheme: `org.gnome.gnome-system-log.filters`. You can edit them with `dconf-editor` (*org>gnome>gnome-system-log>filters*). Replace the space in the name of the filter with a dash (or some other character), and `gnome-system-log` will work again.

Comment: I tried `gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-system-log filters`
 and got `@as []`. After replacing the space with `-` or some other characters, it says "0-5:invalid type declaration". I think I am somewhere close, but what should it be?